# does anyone have any info about the ID in a SharePoint 2013 add-in web URL?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

My security engineer asked what the lifespan of the ID in the add-in web URL was.  Can anyone give me any info on this ID, is it randomly generated, used always for the add-in web, changes every time for the add-in web, specific to an PH Add-in?  anything would be helpful because i can't seem to find anything online explaining the ID and URL

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is randomly generated, aside from a configurable prefix, and once the add-in web is created and the URL assigned, it will remain permanent until that add-in web instance is deleted.

See [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161230.aspx) on MSDN, especially the section "What is the URL for an app for SharePoint?" which states:

> Each installation of an app has a unique URL in your environment. You
>   determine the template for that URL (by specifying a domain name and
>   an app prefix), and then app URLs are automatically generated based on
>   that template.

Comment: Although I suppose the fact that the diagram in that article refers to an "apphash" would imply that there's some sort of algorithm applied to something about the app that then generates the ID, so it's not technically _random_.  But unless you know what that algorithm is, you won't be able to predict the result.